# How to pass Angular directive by reference?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-components, angular-elements

In an existing component template I have this (simplified) element:

```
<input type="button" #refreshPrice />
```

This is picked up (I don't know the correct term) by this property so we can subscribe to it's click event and call a function when the input element is clicked.

I want to replace this `input` element with a component I've developed, which would make it look (simplified) like this:

```
<spinner-button #refreshPrice></spinner-button>
```

This child component has this as its (simplified) template:

```
<button>
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</button>
```

So now the `button` element, in the child component template, needs to have the `#refreshPrice` hash attribute (?) attached.

To do this, perhaps the `spinner-button` element should take the name of the hash attribute as an attribute value. Here is the complete spinner component class file:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "spinner-button",
  templateUrl: "./spinner-button.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./spinner-button.component.css"]
})
export class SpinnerButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}
  
  @Input() targetElement: string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

In theory, the `targetElement` property can then be attached to the `button` element as a hash attribute - but how is this done?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a template ref  to listen on the click event? Or can you also use the `(click)` event directly to call you function?

Comment: The click event is the solution I have settled on. I posted this question because (naïve as I am) I /was/ under the impression that the hashtag attribute was being used for more than it was. I believed that it was allowing the component to reference and listen to events on the input element.

Comment: I have voted to close it based on opinion. Because the opinion held when posted was wrong.

Comment: Looks like xy problem. Could you explain better what are you trying? Also, remember to set # on html elements not selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `@Input()` attribute here allows you to bind a value to a variable on your component, if you want to have the parent do something based on your components data, you might want to use `@Output()` and emit a custom event. If the requirement is just listen to a click event then adding a `(click)=functionToBeCalled()` should help your cause here.

You can refer to the official docs as well:
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs